# DocuSign for Salesforce - relating to closed opportunity or quote record

Tags: salesforce, docusignapi

We have a situation where some of our DocuSign documents do not get signed within the DocuSign system. We have someone that manages these "paper signatures" and then uploads them to DocuSign which connects to Salesforce.

We need to relate these envelopes to either an Opportunity or a Quote to get them to populate fields on these records.

When creatng the envelope, we have the option to "Relate to Salesforce" objects: Leads, Contracts, Opportunities, etc. We tried to use Opportunities and then use the Search to find the Opportunity to attach it to. However, if the Opportunity is in a Closed status (which it is 99% of the time), it will not show up in the search to select.

We could also attach to a Quote, however, there is no option on Salesforce Connect to relate to this object.

Does anyone know a workaround for this that will still allow our person to upload through DS and connect to the appropriate record?

Thanks,

Shannon

Answer (score 0):

It will not unfortunately work with closed ops or quotes.

The only way I can think to do it would be to add a non-required [envelope custom field](https://support.docusign.com/guides/cdse-admin-guide-envelope-custom-fields) in your account called ##SFOpportunity and when uploading that wet signed doc into DocuSign add the objectID as that envelope custom field (it's how the manage package relates back to proper objects when sending from SFDC).

[image]

It's a bit of manual process, but it should work.